# Store MS Access Report into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, reporting-services

I am using MS Access, Excel and Power BI to generate reports from different sources. The final report after ETL, Merging, Filtering, working on it is exported in .CSV and .XLSX format into a specific folder in the computer (we save all in windows 2016 server folder). 
At the same time, I have created SQL Server tables to store those data (only table and columns, but not storing any data yet)

**Is there any way to automatically upload and store data in the SQL Server table each time the new report is generated?** I need to keep the daily/weekly report for historical purposes in a single table.

Probably I need to use some ETL automation tool? Python Scripts?

Comment: You say you already do ETL and save the data in SQL tables. the reports are based on this data.. so not sure what you mean by keep the reports for historical purposes! have you looked at report snapshots?

Comment: SQL Server comes with a ETL tool called SSIS, It will do all the above, get data, transform it, then output it. It looks like you need to automate what you are doing rather that use what I assume is excel manual cracking of data.

Answer (score 4):

This process does not make sense?

You don't save the results of a report. A report is based on a query against the database. So, for the report, you simply execute a query with the date range or criteria.

That way, you might run the report today 1 time, or 10 time. Each time you run this report, it is hitting the database and pulling the data. The results will not change if you run the report for today's data 1 time, or 10 times. And if in 3 months from now you run the report with todays date range, then it should produce the same report.

This idea that in any "sensible" data system, that you attempt to save the results of the report makes no sense at all. You could I suppose generate the report and save it as a PDF, but for what possible reason would you not be able at any time you please to simply re-run the report with the SAME criteria you had before, and thus re-create the report any time you please?

You seem to be taking some kind of spreadsheet approach. You enter data into Excel, and then print it out. So, now you saving a whole copy of the spreadsheet everyday, and that data over time has nothing to do with the pervious data.

This Excel kind of approach is not how a database system works, nor is it how any system with reporting abilities is going to work with any success here.

You can save/put"summary" data into that final database from Access. At that point then you could/should be able to now generate your report as you please in Access (the data will come from that sql server final resting place.

So, the goal and idea here is to generate a report against that final data set.

So, perhaps your question is how can I send some summary data from Access into that final database? Of which then I am free to run reports over and over at will and anytime one pleases. The idea that a report can ONLY be run one time, and that is it? How is that going to work in any production system?

So, you need to send  the data FIRST to the final database. (and if this is summary data that you generate with a bunch of code and processing - then fine).

Once you  send that data (perhaps summary data) to the final database? Well then of course you should be able to run reports "on demand" at any time you please.

It should not matter if you run the report 1 time or 20 times, or in a month run that report 3 more times. That report will have some type of criteria to restrict the data that flows into that report. And it should not matter the number of times and when you re-run tat report in the future - the results should be the same.

If you are asking can you easy send data from Access to SQL server? Sure, but that sending of data certainly can't be attached to WHEN you run a report 1 time, or 10 times. How could people on a mutli-user system run reports at the same time, or even re-run reports?

So, the process of sending that summary data, or new data to sql server has to be separated from the process(s) that allow you to run reports against your final database system.

You can easily run reports in Access that pulls data from the final resting place (SQL server I assume?). But the process of sending that data to sql server needs to be separated from the "event" of running such reports, else you have a VERY difficult time making this system work. What would occur if you need or want or it just so happens that someone re-runs a report? You can't have the reports sending the data to the SQL database. The ETL process has to be separated out from that report generating event.

If your process creates the the summary data (say into some local Access tables), you can then simply use append query(s) from access to linked table(s) that you have in the sql database. So, after your ETL process, you run some append queries in Access that takes the local data and sends it to SQL server.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained it well perhaps my question. Basically I pull data from two different systems (Oracle and another) in excel format. Then in MS Access I create relationship and query. I execute the query and export the final result in a folder every single day.

My question is: How can I store this information automatically in SQL Server in a single table on daily wise? I mean, every day the new information should be added.

Comment: Ok, well in place of the point in time that you export to Excel? Simply replace that with a append query built in Access. The target table can be a simple linked table in that Access application. So, the one append query in place of the Excel export should work fine.